# How a SAS library is different from a Java library

Tags: sas

For someone coming from a java/oracle background, how can I understand the concept of a SAS library? Is it like a Java library (jar)? is it like a oracle database table? or is it a set of functions together with a permanent data store in a table or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SAS library is merely a directory reference that indicates where SAS may expect to find data files (or other things, like format catalogs and macro catalogs).  It does not store any code per se; Base SAS does not generally store compiled code, except for Stored Compiled Macros.

It is most similar to a database schema, if you want to compare it to other things (in that it is a grouping of tables), although it is only superficially similar.  Datasets are accessed similarly, however - `libname.datasetname` dot notation.

For example,

```
libname myfiles "c:\temp";
```

allows you to access any SAS datasets stored in c:\temp (stored as separate files with .sas7bdat extension) like so:

```
data want;
set myfiles.have;
... code ...
run;
```

The un-dot-notated dataset name `want` has a default libref (usually `work`).